# While Loops and Multiple Conditions

Tags: php

Is it possible to write multiple conditions in a while loop? If not, what is an alternative? I tried it and was returned with an error relating the line of code that sets up the conditions for the while loop. Here is an example of what I mean.

```
$s = 1;

while ($result_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) && $s < 5)
{
echo $result_row['id'];
$s++;
}
```

Comment: Sure it's possible. Did you try it? The entire `while` condition, however many components it may have, must evaluate to TRUE or FALSE. That's the only requirement.  Use caution when doing an assignment in a compound statement like that though... `$result_row` may not get what you expect owing to operator precedence.

Comment: Your logic is correct.  What exactly does the error say?

Comment: Absolutely it's possible just like any other control structure. It just has to evaluate to true or false.

Comment: The text of the error will tell you what the problem was.  What was the error?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That is possible, but because `=` has lower [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `&&` you need parentheses to ensure that your statement is interpreted correctly:

```
while (($result_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) && ($s < 5))
```

The parentheses around `$s < 5` are not required here, but I've included them for clarity.

However it would be easier just to modify your query to only return 5 rows, by adding `LIMIT 5`.

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Even better: [mysqli_stmt_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

Comment: The linked precedence does not require the second inner pair of brackets here, so it seems a bit misleading to suggest putting them there. However they do not hurt.

Comment: The sequence of checking condition is Left to Right. So make sure what you want to check first. If you do not want to query DB first then you can check  ($s<5) first and DB query second.  It is just for optimizing conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$s=1
while ($result_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $result_row['id'];
    $s++;
    if($s>5){
        break;
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 0):

while i see nothing wrong in that. the other way round is to do something like this.

```
$s = 1;
while ($result_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if($s < 5) {
        //enter the condition
    }
    $s++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$result_row` is probably being set to the Boolean condition of whether `mysql_fetch_assoc($query)` returns something true-ish and `$s` is less than 5.  So trying to read `$result_row` as a dictionary no longer works.

You can use parenthesis to specify exactly how things get parsed:

```
while (($result_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) && ($s < 5))
```

This way, `$result_row` gets set to `mysql_fetch_assoc($query)`, which is what you want, *and* the loop continues as long as the logical value of that assignment returns something true-ish, as well as `s` is less than 5.