# Adding a simple counter in a while statement with a mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, counter

I am trying to add a simple counter to a while statement in PHP to limit the number of Column values be printed from a table called Table.

In this case I want 10 values to be printed from the query :

```
$link = mysqli_connect("", "", ""); /
$query = "SELECT Column FROM Table";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
$i==0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) && $i < 10){
$e=$row['Column'];
echo $e;
$i++;
echo $i;
}
```

In this case I'm just getting the `$i` values printed up to 10
but none of the `$e` values. If I take out the `&& $i <10` everything works perfectly except that all values of Column are echoed.

I imagine I am doing something horribly wrong with the condition inside the while statement but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: alternatively, you could use a `LIMIT` clause instead of terminating `$i < 10`. and `$i==0; != $i = 0;`

Comment: and isn't `column` and `table` reserved words? or those are just examples

Comment: shouldn't the line `$i==0;` be `$i=0` to make an assignment?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977195/while-loops-and-multiple-conditions

Comment: Thank you that thread has a good answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice where I put the two stars

```
$link = mysqli_connect("", "", ""); /
$query = "SELECT Column FROM Table";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
$i=0; ** $i==0 **;
while(($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && ($i < 10)){ **
  $e=$row['Column'];
  echo $e;
  $i++;
  echo $i;
}
```

I suspect u have some issue with operator precedence (u will need to check).
When u have a sentence `$r= f() && $i<10` U need to verify what is the order of execution, As if `f() && $i` happens first, then u get something completely different than what u expected. That's why I added parentheses to be sure that what u want really happens.
I might be wrong here, but those parentheses are good practice regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("", "", ""); /
$query = "SELECT Column FROM Table LIMIT 10"; // LIMIT wil 'limit' the results to 10 rows
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$e=$row['Column'];
echo $e;
}
```